# Error when using a strpos() function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to filter a foreach that is displaying some results from a API, the connection is made by curl, but when I try to check if the text that I'm sending to the API is on the variable that I post on the form, I'm having this error:

```
Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in /home/**MY-PATH** > : eval()'d code on line 103
```

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
foreach ($obj as $dados) {

    $filtrado = '<div class="result-asso"><img src="' . $dados->imagem . '" alt="" class="img-result" /><strong style="color: rgb(233,116,0);">' . $dados->nome . '</strong><br><strong>Especialidade:</strong> ' . $dados->especialidade1 . '<br><strong>CRM:</strong> ' . $dados->crm . ' / <strong>RQE:</strong> ' . $dados->rqe1 . '<br><strong>Endereço:</strong> ' . $dados->endereco . '</br>' . $dados->cidade . '</br>' . $dados->uf . '</br></div>';
    $esp = strpos($especialidade, $dados->especialidade);
    $cid = strpos($cidade, $dados->cidade);

    //$keyword
    //$especialidade
    //$cidade
    //$estado

    if(!empty($keyword)){ //--------------------------------------------------

        if (!empty($especialidade) && $esp ) {
            unset($dados);
        } else if (!empty($cidade) && $cid )   {
            unset($dados);
        } else if (!empty($estado) && $dados->uf != $estado )  {
            unset($dados);
        } else {
            echo $filtrado;
        }

    } else if(!empty($especialidade)) { //------------------------------------

        if (!empty($cidade) && $cid ) {
            unset($dados);
        } else if (!empty($estado) && $dados->uf != $estado )  {
            unset($dados);
        } else {
            echo $filtrado;
        }

     } else if(!empty($cidade)) { //-------------------------------------------

        if (!empty($estado) && $dados->uf != $estado ) {
            unset($dados);
        } else {
            echo $filtrado;
        }


    } else { //---------------------------------------------------------------
        echo $filtrado;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly like the error says: Your needle - what you are searching for in strpos is empty.

So either  `$dados->especialidade` or `$dados->cidade` ( whichever one is on line 103. ) contains no value so strpos doesn't know what to search for.

Comment: When I 'echo' the two variables they have a value, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's in a loop. You are probably getting an empty object on one of the iterations. When you echo you are probably viewing the values of the object that has values.

Comment: Hmm thats what I realised, so how do I skip the empty ones? And exclude them?

Comment: Skip like this: if(empty($dados->cidade)) { continue; }

Answer (score 1):

Try using `var_dump($dados)` and make sure both `cidade` and `especialidade` are set.

One of these values is empty and therefore can't be used in strpos, which causes the error.

Comment: When I 'echo' the two variables they have a value, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What line is line 103?

Comment: $cid = strpos($cidade, $dados->cidade);